# Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException occurs in Socket.io Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, websocket, socket.io

I am getting the below mentioned error frequently while I am using in the application and I am using the version io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:372)
at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:252)
at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:720)
at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:720)
at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:613)
at org.json.JSONArray.toString(JSONArray.java:585)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
at io.socket.parser.Parser$Encoder.encodeAsString(Parser.java:116)
at io.socket.parser.Parser$Encoder.encode(Parser.java:85)
at io.socket.client.Manager.packet(Manager.java:461)
at io.socket.client.Socket.packet(Socket.java:264)
at io.socket.client.Socket.access$1100(Socket.java:19)
at io.socket.client.Socket$5.run(Socket.java:201)
at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: That is not in socket I/O.  It is in the JSON parser, which indicates very likely corrupt or malformed data being sent.

Comment: You must be editing collection while iterating it .

Comment: The error indicates that you're modifying arrayList (insert, remove etc) while looping. You cannot modify the size of the arraylist while iterating it.

Comment: the crash log states that it is caused by socket.io itself. I also faced similar issue in the middle of app. don't know why?